# Detect whether an email is from a google domain

Tags: java, email, oauth-2.0, google-api

Having an email address I need to know if it is from a google domain or from other domain. I have done some research but I have no clue about how to get this. All I got is linux terminal commands and a Python script which looks for domain's DNS. For example:

1. user@gmail.com : `true`
2. user@mydomaingoogle.com : `true`
3. user@mydomainNOgoogle.com : `false`

I have tried using OAuth with a Calendar API I have already done, which works quite good, but using it with a non-google account doesn't throw exception and I can't see anything different in the response

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what you mean by google domain.   Assuming you mean if the email is attached to a google account you can use the following to test.

IF you are looking for a Google endpoint or API which will tell you if this email is a Google account or not your not going to find one. This is not something that Google is going to want to share.

**Hack**

If you try to invite a non-Google email address to a Google service that requires a Google account (either personal gmail or business), you may get an error message saying something like "unknown email address" if it's a non-Google address. So if you try and invite someone to an event on Google calendar you will at least know if they ifs a google account or not.

Comment: Yes, I meant that. And that might work but I am trying to do it programmatically. Furthermore, in this case I don't even want to use Calendar, just to send an email from that account. Calendar stuff was just what I tried to use with a non-google account

Comment: There is no way to do this programmaticly.   Google is not going to want to give you this information any solution you find is probably going to be a hack like adding a user programmaticly to a folder in google drive or an event on google calendar basicly you need to try and share something with the email to test if its a google account or not.